# document.getElementById(...) in third party JS withing LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, third-party

I'm trying to use [mxgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph) JS with editors. Within `mxClient.js` (main source for mxgraph) there are calls to `document.getElementBy...(...)` to retrieve containers for toolbars, graph etc.

As mentioned [LWC developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_dom_work) :

> Don’t use the window or  document global properties to query for DOM elements.

So, mxGraph is failing...

I was wondering how to deal with this without updating the `myClient.js` file with references to `this.template.querySelector(...)`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not wish to modify the library's code (and that's a perfectly valid choice), you'll have to iframe the graph.
However, that may be a pain due to viewport sizing and scrolling.

Comment: Thanks! You confirmed my fears :) I think I will go with editing the library as it may be painful now but indeed much flexible later than to work with iframes.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT Don’t use the window or  document global properties to query for DOM elements. use  `this.template.querySelector('yourSelector')` it's better.

Comment: Thank you but this exactly the reason why I'm asking this question... What if it is a third party JS which uses `document` ?

Comment: honestly i do not know but i think you should try to see if the third party is compatible with lwc. If so, you should not worry about it.